# CQ5 timezone issue

Tags: aem

I am facing an issue with setting time on page properties on cq:Page. The time being set into the JCR is getting converted to the timezone that is set in author’s machine. For example: time being set when author is in India is saved as +5:30 while in NY it is being set with -4:00 offset. Is there any way this can be fixed ?

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you want to change this, unless I misunderstood the issue. Time is linear, so at any given point in time, there are as many possible ways to express the time as there are valid time zones. Anyone who views that page information through the application (not directly viewing the JCR) should see that timestamp converted to their local system time.